# Aristotle's Categories: Original Greek text for Chapter 2?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

I'm trying to find the original Greek for this passage [in the Octavius Own Oxford edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vku5DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA4).  Does anyone know of a source?

> Likewise also some things are predicated of a certain subject, yet are in no subject, as "the man" is predicated of a subject, i.e. of "some certain man", yet is in no subject.  Others, again are in a subject, yet are not predicated of any subject, (I mean by a thing being in a subject, that which is in any thing not as a part, but which cannot subsist without that which it is,) as "a certain grammatical art" is in a subject, "the soul", but is not predicated of any; and "this white thing" is in a subject, "the body" (for all "colour" is in "body"), but is predicated of no subject.

Also, I understand there are a few interpretations of this section.  I'm trying to look at the original Greek as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do not know Greek, but that 'which is in a subject, but not present in a subject', in all its variations, is primary 'ousia', or substance. This compares favorably with Spinoza's 'substance' or that which is 'causa sui' or cause of itself. CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aristotle's *Categories* in [*LCL* 325: 14-15](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/aristotle-the_categories/1938/pb_LCL325.15.xml?result=1&rskey=NhkXm4):

> Τῶν ὄντων τὰ μὲν καθ᾿ ὑποκειμένου τινὸς λέγεται, ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ οὐδενί ἐστιν, οἷον ἄνθρωπος καθ᾿ ὑποκειμένου μὲν λέγεται τοῦ τινὸς ἀνθρώπου, ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ οὐδενί ἐστι· τὰ δὲ ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μέν ἐστι, καθ᾿ ὑποκειμένου δὲ οὐδενὸς λέγεται (ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ λέγω, ὃ ἔν τινι 25μὴ ὡς μέρος ὑπάρχον ἀδύνατον χωρὶς εἶναι τοῦ ἐν ᾧ ἐστίν), οἷον ἡ τὶς γραμματικὴ ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μέν ἐστι τῇ ψυχῇ, καθ᾿ ὑποκειμένου δ᾿ οὐδενὸς λέγεται, καὶ τὸ τὶ λευκὸν ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μὲν τῷ σώματί ἐστιν (ἅπαν γὰρ χρῶμα ἐν σώματι), καθ᾿ ὑποκειμένου δὲ οὐδενὸς λέγεται·
>
> <sup>But as for the things that are meant, when we thus speak of uncombined words, you can predicate some of a subject, but they never are present in one. You can predicate ‘man,’ for example, of this or that man as the subject, but man is not found in a subject. By ‘in,’ ‘present,’ ‘found in a subject’ I do not mean present or found as its parts are contained in a whole; I mean that it cannot exist as apart from the subject referred to. And then there is that class of things which are present or found in a subject, although they cannot be asserted of any known subject whatever. A piece of grammatical knowledge is there in the mind as a subject but cannot be predicated of any known subject whatever. Again, a particular whiteness is present or found in a body (all colour implies some such basis as what we intend by ‘a body’) but cannot itself be asserted of any known subject whatever.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer since the texts may not be "the Octavius Own Oxford edition".

There is a Greek text of Aristotle's *The Categories* on the Internet Archive with a translation by Harold P. Cook.

https://archive.org/details/organoncooke01arisuoft/page/n25

[Wikisource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_(Aristotle)#Text_and_translations) also has the original Greek text linked at the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_(Aristotle)

Answer (score 0):

Tῶν ὄντων τὰ μὲν καθ' ὑποκειμένου τινὸς λέγεται, ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ οὐδενί ἐστιν, οἷον ἄνθρωπος καθ' ὑποκειμένου μὲν λέγεται τοῦ τινὸς ἀνθρώπου, ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ οὐδενί ἐστι• τὰ δὲ ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μέν ἐστι, καθ' ὑποκειμένου δὲ οὐδενὸς λέγεται (ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ δὲ λέγω ὃ ἔν τινι μὴ ὡς μέρος ὑπάρχον ἀδύνατον χωρὶς εἶναι τοῦ ἐν ὧ ἐστίν), οἷον ἡ τὶς γραμματικὴ ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μέν ἐστι τῇ ψυχῇ, καθ' ὑποκειμένου δὲ οὐδενὸς λέγεται, καὶ τὸ τὶ λευκὸν ἐν ὑποκειμένῳ μέν τῶ σώματι ἐστιν (ἅπαν γὰρ χρῶμα ἐν σώματι), καθ' ὑποκειμένου δὲ οὐδενὸς λέγεται•

[Discussion is about how things are described-stated.]

Something existing can be part of a larger grouping, but all in the group are not that [something existing]. A particular human can be called “human” but not all in the grouping of “humanity” are this particular human. The category [humanity] would exist without this one [human], but this human could not exist without the existing category [humanity]. All with the ability to “read and write” are humans, because it is part of the “human nature”, but it is claimed that not all “humans” can do so. And the illumination can show an item, all items have coloring, but it is claimed that it doesn’t happen to all.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).